# Lipschitz implies bounded gradient with any norm?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, lipschitz-functions

Assume I have a differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is $L$-Lipschitz with respect to a norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$:
$$ \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n, |f(x) - f(y)| \le L\|x-y\|.  $$
I know that if $f$ is further assumed to be convex, and $\|\cdot\|$ is the euclidian norm, then convexity implies
$$ L\|\nabla f(x)\|_2 \ge f(x + \nabla f(x)) - f(x) \ge \langle \nabla f(x), \nabla f(x)\rangle = \| \nabla f(x)\|_2^2, $$
thus $\|\nabla f(x)\|_2 \le L$.

But does $\|\nabla f(x)\| \le L$ still hold if $\|\cdot\|$ is any norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$? And if $f$ is only assumed differentiable?

Comment: That is what I was thinking... I am quite sure I have seen this argument used to upper bound the L1-norm in some optimization papers, but that does not seem to be true to me, so I was wondering whether there were some differentiability arguments I am not aware of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that for a differentiable function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, its gradient is defined thanks to the euclidean structure of $\mathbb{R}^n$: it is the only vector field such that for all $x$ and $u$
$$
\mathrm{d}_xf\cdot u = \langle \nabla f(x),u\rangle.
$$

In what follows, all gradients $\nabla f$ are the classic euclidean gradients defined thanks to the usual euclidean structure.

An important result is that if $f$ is Lipschitz *for some norm*, then it is almost everywhere differentiable, and is Lipschitz for any norm. Moreover, the euclidean gradient is then defined almost everywhere.

Notice that for the euclidean norm, one has $\|\nabla f(x)\|_2 = \|\mathrm{d}_xf\|_2$, where this second norm is the operator norm subordinate to the euclidean one: it is because by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$
|\mathrm{d}_xf\cdot u| = |\langle \nabla f (x),u\rangle| \leqslant \|\nabla f (x) \|_2 \|u\|_2,
$$
hence $\|\mathrm{d}_xf\| \leqslant \|\nabla f(x)\|_2$, and equality is reached for $u = \nabla f(x)$. So saying $f$ is $L$-Lipschitz show that $\|\nabla f\|_2 \leqslant L$ almost everywhere.

But if you consider another norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$, there is no reason for (the above vector field) $\nabla f$ to stay bounded *with the same constant*: indeed, the equivalence of norms in a finite dimensional vector space assures that for any norm $\|\cdot\|$, there exists a constant $C>0$ such that
$$
\|\nabla f(x)\| \leqslant C\cdot \|\nabla f (x) \|_2.
$$
A counter example to having the same constant $L$ is just the following: suppose $f(x) = \langle u,x \rangle$ for a given $u \in \mathbb{R}$ and for $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ the usual inner product. Then $\nabla f \equiv u$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, hence $\|\nabla f \|_2 = \|u\|_2$. But if one measures $\nabla f$ thanks to $\|\cdot\|_{\lambda}=\lambda \|\cdot \|_2$ with $\lambda >0$, one has
$$
\|\nabla f \|_{\lambda} = \lambda \|u\|_2  
$$
which is strictly greater than $L = \|u\|_2$ if $\lambda >1$.

To conclude, note that that I never used any convexity assumption, but I used only the Lipschitz one.

Comment: I see, convexity seemed to be overkill there. Actually, I am trying to upperbound gradients' $L1$-norm. Norms equivalence works but it depends on the dimension. Assuming that $f$ is restricted to a set where $\|x\|_1 \le M$ for some $M > 0$, would it hold that $\|\nabla f\|_1 = O(L)$ or something similar? I am very confused about this since they seem to use such a result there (page 5), but I am surely missing something: https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2015/file/52d080a3e172c33fd6886a37e7288491-Paper.pdf.

Comment: Well, I have absolutely no skill in optimisation, but if you are refering to the sentence "*We can bound the error in terms of the L1-Lipschitz constant, which can be much smaller than th L2-Lipschitz constant*", I find it weird: I did some (possibly false) computations and it seems to me that the $L_2$ Lipschitz constant is smaller than the $L_1$ Lipschitz constant. In fact I have something like $C_2 \leqslant C_1 \leqslant \sqrt{n}C_2$.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. :) I think inequalities between L1 and L2 norms give $|f(x) - f(y)| \le C_2 \|x-y\|_2 \le C_2 \|x-y\|_1$ thus $C_2 \ge C_1$, and $|f(x) - f(y)| \le C_1 \|x-y\|_1 \le \sqrt{n}L_1 \|x-y\|_2$ which yields $\sqrt{n} C_1 \ge C_2$, since these constants should be defined as the smallest upper bound.

Comment: For the record, an upper bound such as $\|\nabla f(x)\|_1 \le L_1$ does not generally hold. However, convexity with $y = x + \nabla_i f(x) e_i$ (where $i$ is chosen such that $\| \nabla f(x)\|_\infty = | \nabla_i f(x) |$) gives $\| \nabla f(x) \|_\infty \le L_1$, which gives the upper bound $\langle s, \nabla f(x) \rangle \le \| s \|_1 L_1$ in the above paper using Hölder's inequality.